# Añadir elemento a listview desde otro activity diferente

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Que tal! Deseo meter en un listview de un activity llamado cesta elementos de un navigation drawer activity. Tengo una variable llamada K que lleno de un elemento del dummy del navigation drawer, pero quiero que en el fragmento de este activity, por medio de un botón se mande al lisview de la clase cesta

Clase Framento

```
//-----------CLASE FRAGMENTO----------------
//Aquí es de donde se envia el elemento para el Listview
 public class ProductoDetailFragment extends Fragment {

String K;

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.Nombre);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre)).setText(mItem.Nombre + "\n");
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtClave)).setText(mItem.Clave + "\n");
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion)).setText(mItem.Descripcion + "\n");
        K = mItem.Nombre;
        Log.v(TAG, "Variable K llenada con el valor: " + K);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Clase cesta

```
//-----------CLASE CESTA----------------
//Aquí se debe recibir el elemento y añadirlo al listview

public class CestaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView Lista;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
ArrayList<String> adapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cesta);

    Lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapt);
    Lista.setAdapter(adaptador);


}

}
```

Comment: por que no usas un intent para enviar el dato y mostrarlo en el listview ...

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.